# Why do some commands return output but not others for exec.Command()

Tags: go, cmd, darwin

I am trying to figure out why some shell commands work with goloang exec.Command and others don't when they all return the same result when entered in terminal.  I basically would like to use the same command for windows and mac binary (exec.Command("where", "go").Output()).

These specifically:

```
goInstalled, err := exec.Command("where", "go").Output() // does not return output on mac when compiled but does in terminal command. DOES return output on windows compiled.

goInstalled, err := exec.Command("which", "go").Output() // does not return output on mac when compiled but does in terminal command

goInstalled, err := exec.Command("command", "-v", "go").Output() // returns output when compiled and as terminal command (mac only)
```

I would like to use the same command for windows and mac (darwin) if possible rather than create two separate functions to check if things are installed on users machine.

Comment: You must be ignoring `err`.

Comment: by "no output" i mean it does trigger err != nil block and the value is [] for goInstalled for these. goInstalled, err := exec.Command("command", "-v", "go").Output() does not trigger err != nil block and returns an output [byte numbers]

Comment: exec.Command does *not* execute shell commands. It executes the *program* given as the first argument. Shell built-ins don't work without executing a shell explicitly. In this case though you can simply call [exec.LookPath](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath).

Answer (score 4):

The main issue you're running into here is that `exec.Command` executes *programs*, where the commands you're trying to use are actually built-ins.

In order to use built-ins, you need to find them using `exec.LookPath`, and they're not generally available outside of a shell.

If you must, you can also execute the command from *within* a shell, by having a shell be first argument:

```
exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "command -v foo")
```

Comment: No need to call LookPath yourself: "If name contains no path separators, Command uses LookPath to resolve name to a complete path" https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command

Comment: My mistake, I'll update my comment. Thanks for the catch!